# Is it safe to stain some small wood pieces with Danish oil in my basement?

Tags: safety, staining

Is it safe to stain some small wood pieces with Danish oil in my basement? Nobody uses the basement but I am concerned about fumes leaking up into the main house. It is Watco Danish oil.

Comment: "Safe" is mostly a matter of opinion. What exhausting means do you have in your basement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oil finishes have been used on wood in homes for years, I have done several hard wood floors with this same brand it drys fairly quickly but you should make sure to have adequate fresh air for several hours, a couple of boards may not be much but some folks are very sensitive to the odors. Make sure to follow the mfg instructions and by following  them the product is safe to use.